# como ejecutar git commit

Tags: git

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedo realizar un nuevo commit, y ya he creado un user y email y nada no me deja. Ya he intentado con proyectos pequeños y aun nada.

comienzo con git init
luego git status
git add -A
cuando voy a realizar un commit me sale ese mensaje y ya he creado un user muchas veces

Comment: Hola @HectorRperez que diferencia hay entre git add . y git add -A?

Comment: El mensaje te dice qué hacer. Ejecuta esas 2 sentencias `git config --global ...` ajustando la sentencia para que incluya tu nombre y email, y luego vuelve a intentar el `git commit`.

Comment: Soy nuevo en git amigo, la cosa es que estoy empezando y no me deja crear commit... no se si es por una configuración

Comment: Claro amigo entiendo que dice el mensaje... realizo eso y continuo si poder crear un commit

Comment: Amigo estoy utilizando el comando git config --global user.name no hay ningun error, utilizo perfectamente los comandos en git

Comment: Si ejecutas solamente `git config --global user.email` y `git config --global user.name`, ¿qué resultados recibes?

Comment: si pruebas con git status que te aparece?

Comment: Si utilizo estos comandos me registra correctamente mi nombre y correo git config --global user.email y git config --global user.name

Comment: prueba de esta manera git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git

Comment: Si ya lo has intentado, la pregunta real sería, ¿Qué mensaje arrojan los comandos que git te pide realizar antes de hacer `git add`?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes configurar `git` con los siguientes comandos a como te dice la consola:

```
git config --global user.email 'tuemail@email.com'
git config --global user.name 'ExampleNameOrUserGit'
```

> **Nota:** al hacer `push` por primera vez te pedirá tus credenciales registrados [Git](http://gitlab.com)

Comment: Okye amigo!! Gracias

Comment: @HectoRperez si esta respuesta te ayudo puedes aceptarla como mejor respuesta y cerrar esta pregunta ?